# Program is running according to Netbeans, but makes no progress and java.exe barely uses the CPU

Tags: java, netbeans, cpu-usage

I am new to this site, so I hope I wont violate any unwritten rules here... ;-)

I am programmed a heuristic for the Travelling Salesman Problem which first creates a Minimum Spanning Tree, extends it to create an Euler Tour an then derives a Hamiltoninan Circle from that Euler Tour.

The program works perfectly well for graphs of up to about 3700 vertices (although it takes some time, roughly three hours on my Laptop), but now there seems to be trouble when I try to solve a graph of ~4300 vertices.

The MST is created as always, but at some point while creating the Euler-Tour the CPU seems to "lose intrest" in my program. According to Windows Task Manager the java.exe process uses in about 25% of the CPU (one of the four cores) while solving the smaller graphs, but now it is down to 0 - 1%. According to the Netbeans IDE the program is still runnig, but I am not sure what to make of these informations.

Maybe it is relevant that I had to overcome some OutOfMemory-Errors (Heap Space), which I solved by a combination of brute force - I allowed the project to create a 4090 MB Heap (4 GB RAM)- and some changes to the code which are probably not relevant here.

If someone could give me a hint what might be the problem I'd be pretty happy.

Regards,
Phil

Comment: Do you have any logging going on while executing the program? Perhaps it halts at somepoint and just seems to be running

Comment: Try and obtain a thread dump, there may be a deadlock somewhere

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you have a thread which hasn't finished from within your program.

Your thread might be alive because it was sent to sleep and never woken up, or there might be a deadlock.  I recommended that you use [visualvm](http://visualvm.java.net/download.html) to determine if you have a thread still running, and even see at what point in your program you go from high CPU usage to low CPU usage, along with some logging, might help you figure out the exact issue.